# Can I ensure that NVCC has managed to place an array in registers?

Tags: arrays, compilation, cuda, nvcc

A CUDA kernel with some local, fixed-size array may get compiled so that the array resides in the thread's "local memory", or - if NVCC can determine the position of each array access at compile time, and there are enough registers available - the array might be broken up with its elements residing in registers.

Is it possible to check or to ensure, either via the code or as part of the build process, that a specific array, or all local arrays in a kernel, have been fit into registers? Is doing so supported by any tool?

Comment: You may output ptx and search for local data declaration. Local data had always had the same name in my own experience. Also, the load will be local, hence ld.local ptx instructions should be issued.

Comment: @FlorentDUGUET: Are you sure the SASS won't 'drop' locality? That is, except when there aren't enough registers?

Comment: I am mentioning ptx. I will come back to you with a sample.

Answer (score 2):

**At runtime**

You may use the `CU_FUNC_ATTRIBUTE_LOCAL_SIZE_BYTES` as a hint on whether your array has been registrified; using CUDA driver API function [`cuFuncGetAttribute`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__EXEC.html#group__CUDA__EXEC_1g5e92a1b0d8d1b82cb00dcfb2de15961b). But for some use cases, runtime may be too late.

**At compile time**

You want to have a look at the generated ptx file (using --keep option in nvcc).

The local data declation is identified as `.local` in the ptx. Here is a small example, with a kernel.

```
#define ww 65

__global__ void kernel(int W, int H, const int *a, int *b)
{
    int buffer[ww];

    for (int i = threadIdx.x; i < H; i += blockDim.x)
    {
        #pragma unroll
        for (int w = 0; w < ww; ++w)
            buffer[w] = a[i + w * W];

        for (int j = 5; j < H - 5; ++j)
        {
            buffer[j % ww] = a[i + (j + 6) * W];

            int s = 0;
            #pragma unroll 
            for (int w = 0; w < ww; ++w)
                s += buffer[w];

            b[i + (j + 6) * W] = s;
        }
    }
}
```

When compiled there is a declaration of a local variable:

```
.visible .entry _Z6kerneliiPKiPi(
    .param .u32 _Z6kerneliiPKiPi_param_0,
    .param .u32 _Z6kerneliiPKiPi_param_1,
    .param .u64 _Z6kerneliiPKiPi_param_2,
    .param .u64 _Z6kerneliiPKiPi_param_3
)
{
    .local .align 4 .b8     __local_depot0[260];
    .reg .b64   %SP;
    .reg .b64   %SPL;
    .reg .pred  %p<5>;
    .reg .b32   %r<219>;
    .reg .b64   %rd<81>;
```

However, when rolling the buffer, `buffer` is always accessed with known indices and registers may be obtained - no local storage:

```
#define ww 65

__global__ void kernel(int W, int H, const int *a, int *b)
{
    int buffer[ww];

    for (int i = threadIdx.x; i < H; i += blockDim.x)
    {
        #pragma unroll
        for (int w = 0; w < ww; ++w)
            buffer[w] = a[i + w * W];

        for (int j = 5; j < H - 5; ++j)
        {
            #pragma unroll 
            for (int w = 0; w < ww-1; ++w)
                buffer[w] = buffer[w + 1];
            buffer[ww - 1] = a[i + (j + 6) * W];

            int s = 0;
            #pragma unroll 
            for (int w = 0; w < ww; ++w)
                s += buffer[w];

            b[i + (j + 6) * W] = s;
        }
    }
}
```

Yields the following ptx:

```
.visible .entry _Z6kerneliiPKiPi(
    .param .u32 _Z6kerneliiPKiPi_param_0,
    .param .u32 _Z6kerneliiPKiPi_param_1,
    .param .u64 _Z6kerneliiPKiPi_param_2,
    .param .u64 _Z6kerneliiPKiPi_param_3
)
{
    .reg .pred  %p<5>;
    .reg .b32   %r<393>;
    .reg .b64   %rd<240>;
```

Note that depending on the number of registers available, the number of required registers may not fit. These are virtual registers (which has somehow changed in recent versions of CUDA). Meaning that the absence of `.local .align 4 .b8     __local_depot` is a prerequisite, but not sufficient.

You need to look at the SASS then. Using `nvdisasm` on your generated `.cubin`, you want to search for `STL` instruction which stands for STore Local, as described briefly [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/index.html#maxwell-pascal). Here are parts of the two disassembled cubins compiled with two different values of `--maxrregcount` compiler switch - first for 32 (see the many occurrences of `STL`):

```
//--------------------- .text._Z6kerneliiPKiPi    --------------------------
    .section    .text._Z6kerneliiPKiPi,"ax",@progbits
    .sectioninfo    @"SHI_REGISTERS=32"
    .align  32
        .global         _Z6kerneliiPKiPi
        .type           _Z6kerneliiPKiPi,@function
        .size           _Z6kerneliiPKiPi,(.L_25 - _Z6kerneliiPKiPi)
        .other          _Z6kerneliiPKiPi,@"STO_CUDA_ENTRY STV_DEFAULT"
_Z6kerneliiPKiPi:
.text._Z6kerneliiPKiPi:
        /*0008*/                   MOV R1, c[0x0][0x20];
        /*0010*/         {         IADD32I R1, R1, -0x180;
        /*0018*/                   S2R R0, SR_TID.X;        }
        /*0028*/                   ISETP.GE.AND P0, PT, R0, c[0x0][0x144], PT;
        /*0030*/                   NOP;
        /*0038*/                   NOP;
        /*0048*/               @P0 EXIT;
.L_3:
        /*0050*/                   IADD R2, R0, c[0x0][0x140];
        /*0058*/                   MOV R30, c[0x0][0x140];
        /*0068*/                   ISCADD R5.CC, R2.reuse, c[0x0][0x148], 0x2;
        /*0070*/         {         SHR R3, R2, 0x1e;
        /*0078*/                   STL [R1+0x14], R5;        }
        /*0088*/                   ISCADD R2, R30.reuse, R0.reuse, 0x1;
        /*0090*/                   ISCADD R4, R30.reuse, R0.reuse, 0x2;
        /*0098*/                   ISCADD R20, R30, R0, 0x3;
        /*00a8*/                   IADD.X R5, R3, c[0x0][0x14c];
        /*00b0*/         {         SHR R3, R2.reuse, 0x1e;
        /*00b8*/                   STL [R1+0x10], R5;        }
        /*00c8*/                   ISCADD R2.CC, R2, c[0x0][0x148], 0x2;
        /*00d0*/                   STL [R1+0x8], R2;
        /*00d8*/                   SHR R5, R4, 0x1e;
        /*00e8*/                   IADD.X R2, R3, c[0x0][0x14c];
        /*00f0*/         {         ISCADD R4.CC, R4, c[0x0][0x148], 0x2;
        /*00f8*/                   STL [R1+0x4], R2;        }
```

Then for 255 - no occurence of `STL`:

```
//--------------------- .text._Z6kerneliiPKiPi    --------------------------
    .section    .text._Z6kerneliiPKiPi,"ax",@progbits
    .sectioninfo    @"SHI_REGISTERS=124"
    .align  32
        .global         _Z6kerneliiPKiPi
        .type           _Z6kerneliiPKiPi,@function
        .size           _Z6kerneliiPKiPi,(.L_25 - _Z6kerneliiPKiPi)
        .other          _Z6kerneliiPKiPi,@"STO_CUDA_ENTRY STV_DEFAULT"
_Z6kerneliiPKiPi:
.text._Z6kerneliiPKiPi:
        /*0008*/                   MOV R1, c[0x0][0x20];
        /*0010*/                   S2R R0, SR_TID.X;
        /*0018*/                   ISETP.GE.AND P0, PT, R0, c[0x0][0x144], PT;
        /*0028*/                   NOP;
        /*0030*/                   NOP;
        /*0038*/               @P0 EXIT;
        /*0048*/                   MOV R46, c[0x0][0x144];
        /*0050*/                   IADD R47, RZ, -c[0x0][0x140];
        /*0058*/                   IADD32I R46, R46, -0x5;
        /*0068*/                   SHL R47, R47, 0x2;
.L_3:
        /*0070*/                   ISETP.LT.AND P0, PT, R46, 0x6, PT;
        /*0078*/               @P0 BRA `(.L_1);
        /*0088*/                   MOV R2, c[0x0][0x140];
        /*0090*/                   ISCADD R2, R2, R0, 0x6;
        /*0098*/                   SHR R27, R2.reuse, 0x1e;
        /*00a8*/                   ISCADD R26.CC, R2, c[0x0][0x148], 0x2;
        /*00b0*/                   SHR R48, R47, 0x1f;
        /*00b8*/                   IADD.X R27, R27, c[0x0][0x14c];
        /*00c8*/         {         IADD R44.CC, R47.reuse, R26;
        /*00d0*/                   LDG.E R49, [R26];        }
        /*00d8*/                   IADD.X R45, R48.reuse, R27;
        /*00e8*/         {         IADD R42.CC, R47.reuse, R44  SLOT 0;
        /*00f0*/                   LDG.E R44, [R44]  SLOT 1;        }
        /*00f8*/                   IADD.X R43, R48.reuse, R45;
        /*0108*/         {         IADD R38.CC, R47, R42  SLOT 0;
        /*0110*/                   LDG.E R42, [R42]  SLOT 1;        }
```

Very much like you I assume, I wish that all of this was better documented.

Comment: So, to ensure my arrays are optimized out of local memory, I basically need to do some grep'ing. But then how will I know what the .local's name is going to be? I suppose I could use the size in bytes to search, but still.

Comment: I edited my answer with a link to runtime information, but it may not be satisfactory for you. I wish there was better options, and should you have some I would be interested, but for some reason I don't see how, as a compiler developer, it is possible to easily report and express in a way that does not end-up with a grep involved. `__local_depot` seems to be a good keyword in practice, no certainty though. Again, this is more experimental than documentation-based.